# Concern about End of Support for Python Runtimes (python27 and python37)

Tags: google-app-engine

Currently we have used Python runtimes as below for our applications on Google App Engine

> Runtime: Python27 and Runtime: Python37

We have seen that 2 above runtimes will be reached End of Support on 2024-01-30.

> Python 3.7 Ubuntu 18.04 python37 2024-01-30

> Python 2.7 App Engine Legacy Environment python27 2024-01-30

So what are the consequences on 2024-01-30. What are the impacts?

From the runtime lifecycle (https://apc01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.google.com%2Fappengine%2Fdoc...)

> End of support
> When runtime components reach the end of support date:
> Google will no longer apply security updates or patches to components of the runtime environment.
> Your application will continue to run and receive traffic.
> You will no longer be able to create and/or update the application on the unsupported runtime.
> Issues arising from the use of an unsupported runtime will not be eligible for technical support

=> Looks like the application still continue to run and receive traffic.
However, we can't update our application and can't deploy a new version for our existing services with python27 and python37 runtimes, right?
=> Does it mean that we need to the upgrade for our runtime before 2024-01-30 for python27 and python37, right?

> Notification period
> App Engine will begin issuing in-app notifications 90 days before the application reaches end of support. Upon notification, you should prepare to upgrade your application to a newer runtime that is supported in the standard environment.

=> Does it mean that 90 days before 2024-01-30, we will receive the notification, right?

Thanks,

Comment: My question is how can i update my app because it has developed on Python2.7 from last 5 year, and python 3 does not sport some old programming concept? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean that we need to upgrade our runtime before 2024-01-30 for python27 and python37, right?

Yes you are correct, You will no longer be able to create and/or update the application on the unsupported runtime and you have to update your runtime before 2024-01-30

As you have pointed out  [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/runtime-lifecycle) confirms below.

> When a language version is no longer actively maintained by the respective community, App Engine will also stop providing maintenance and support for that language runtime. Before a runtime reaches the end of the support phase as described in the runtimes support schedule, Google will provide a notification to customers.

> Does it mean that 30 days before 2024-01-30, we will receive the notification, right?

No, I think you have missed to see the correct number. App Engine will begin issuing in-app notifications *90 days* before the application reaches the end of support and not before 30 days..

Upon notification, you should prepare to upgrade your application to a newer runtime that is supported in the standard environment.

You can follow the [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences) to upgrade the version in appengine.

Comment: My question is how can i update my app because it has developed on Python2.7 from last 5 year, and python 3 does not sport some old programming concept?